# Tracking Ajax Pageloads with Universal Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I just updated our new Ajax webpage and I am having trouble figuring out how to track pageviews for each ajax page loaded. So far, Google Analytics only reports views to the index/home page when internal ajax pages are loaded, but not each individual ajax page.

Here's the code that is included in the template page container, which loads at the bottom of each individual ajax page :

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-70690965-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview', document.URL);

</script>
```

How can I track ajax page loads?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to check for ajaxComplete:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e,x,o){
   console.info('ajax completed');
   ga('send','page', '/vpv/ajax/page');
}
```

When an ajaxComplete is called, you can send a virtual page view.

Comment: The ajaxComplete function is a listener that executes the code within the function when it detects ajax calls. In my example, when the new content is loaded, a message will be displayed in the console and a GA pageview will be sent with a virtual page view.